# CSS Блымает картинка при загрузке

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть изображение для бэкграуна с размером 4к
Когда открываю страницу которую создал. То изображение не сразу появляется, а блымает мол прогружается.
Как от этого избавится? Просто когда уменьшил до 1600px не помогло совсем. Как можно поправить?

```
body {
    font-family     : sans-serif;
    background: url("../img/background.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: а что такое `блымает` ?

Comment: а вообще слишком большой размер

Comment: @Pavel Grishaev я вообще не люблю сокращение слов, что такое РБ?

Answer (score 0):

Бесспорно хочется, чтобы изображения на сайте были как можно качественнее. Но, за качество приходится платить размером файла и, как следствие, временем для его загрузки. Если скорость приёма/передачи данных при этом небольшая, то наблюдать пустой экран не очень приятно.

Чтобы избежать подобной ситуации, необходимо поставить "заглушки" из изображения низкого качества и фонового цвета:

```css
body {
  /* Порядок слоёв важен! Высокое качество, низкое качество, цветовая заглушка */
  background-image: url("../img/background.jpg"), url("../img/background_low.jpg"), radial-gradient(#eee, #48f);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
```

- Изображение низкого качества делаем в графическом редакторе или конвертере из оригинального изображения, путём пропорционального уменьшения размеров сторон и установкой максимальных параметров сжатия (естественно, что в разумных пределах).
- Для цветовой заглушки, лучше использовать какой-либо из градиентов (*radial-* или *linear-*), подобрав цвета наиболее подходящие по палитре на изображении (например, если на картинке у Вас изображены облака, то в градиенте будут голубой и белый цвета).

Также желательно использовать медиа-запросы (*@media*), чтобы на основе разрешения экрана, подгружать картинку с близкими параметрами. Избыточное качество не даст никакого эффекта, кроме увеличения трафика и времени загрузки. Так, на экране 800х600, будут выглядеть одинаково, что картинка с такими же размерами, что картинка в 4K.